# read html table content from remote website using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read html table data from remote website and store in a list or array using java script. If I have html like the one below from a remote website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get table data and store it to an array i.e 
         index 0          index 1        index 2
array=| Jill Smith 50 | Eve Jackson 94| John Doe 80 |

```
var result;
    function xmlparser() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.example.com",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) { 
                result = data.table;
                alert(result);
            },

            }
        });             
    }
```

I wanted alert( alert(result) ) to display table with the content-assuming the html above is from http://www.example.com.

Comment: We are not a code producing factory... Show us what you've tried so far and tell us where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: I showed what I have tried and I am stuck a getting html table data from a remote website

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = []; // Create empty array
$("tr").each(function(i, el) { // iterate through all TR elements
  result.push(el.innerText.replace(/\t/g, " "));
  // no need to get each element and concat, 
  // innerText will do it if you replace tabs for spaces
});
console.log(result); // ["Jill Smith 50", "Eve Jackson 94", "John Doe 80"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etLdmzt3/

Comment: This solution does not work  for html table from a remote website. I am looking for a solution that works for html table from a remote website. I have already this provided answer. thanks for the answer.....

Comment: i answered your original question, accept this question and make another question with your revised question. you can't edit your question everytime i answer.

Comment: The original question starts "I want to read html table data **from remote website**..."

I'm unsure how the original question is answered here.